# How to see if DataStore supports Thin Provisioning via PowerCli(VMware)

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

When selecting storage during VM creation, we can see if this storage supports Thin Provisioning or not(Supported/Not supported). How can I show it via PowerCli for script perspective?

My command so far, only this column is missing:

```
Get-Datastore -server xxx -name xxx | Select Name, Datacenter,CapacityGB,FreeSpaceGB,Type,
@{N="Provisioned (GB)"; E={[math]::round(($_.ExtensionData.Summary.Capacity - $_.ExtensionData.Summary.FreeSpace + $_.ExtensionData.Summary.Uncommitted)/1GB,2) }}
```

Output:

```
Name             : xxx
Datacenter       : xxx
CapacityGB       : 4654.75
FreeSpaceGB      : 3253.978515625
Provisioned (GB) : 2279.13
Type             : VMFS
```

Bonus question: how can I change the current output for horizontal view(table columns)?

Comment: This [link](https://code.vmware.com/forums/2530/vsphere-powercli#532208) answers your first question.

Comment: Thanks, nice tool. But weird, I see "Unknown" via CLI and "Supported" via VSphere gui. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the 'PerFileThinProvisioningSupported' property, it's located: `$ds.ExtensionData.Capability.PerFileThinProvisioningSupported`

Bonus question, pipe what you have to: `Format-Table`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kyle Ruddy, final answer:

```
Get-Datastore -server xxx -name xxx | Select Name, Datacenter,CapacityGB,FreeSpaceGB,Type,
>> @{N="Provisioned (GB)"; E={[math]::round(($_.ExtensionData.Summary.Capacity - $_.ExtensionData.Summary.FreeSpace + $_.ExtensionData.Summary.Uncommitted)/1GB,2) }},
>> @{N="Thin Provisioning"; E={($_.ExtensionData.Capability.PerFileThinProvisioningSupported)}} | format-table
```